# Error in getting second models value in Yii multimodel form

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have the database like this

```
+------------------+
|     Invoices     |
+------------------+
| id               |
| customer_id (Fk) |
| description      |
+------------------+

+------------------+
|    Customers     |
+------------------+
| id               |
| firstname        |
| lastname         |
| description      |
+------------------+
```

So as per my requirment I made [multimodel](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models/).In that multimodel Customers model is loaded in Invoices model.Now the actionCreate() of invoice controller is like this

```
public function actionCreate()
  {
    $model=new Invoices;
    $customers = new Customers;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
    if (isset($_POST['Invoices'],$_POST['Customers']))
    {
      $model->attributes = $_POST['Invoices'];
      $customers->attributes = $_POST['Customers'];
      $valid = $model->validate();
      $valid = $customers->validate();
      if($valid)
      {
        $customers->save(false);
        $model->customer_id = $customers->getPrimaryKey();
        $model->save(false);
         $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
      }
    }
    $this->render('create',array(
      'model'=>$model,
      'customers' => $customers,
    ));
  }
```

The actionView() is looking like this

```
  public function actionView($id)
  {
    $this->render('view',array(
      'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
      'customers'=>Invoices::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>$_GET['id']))->customer_id,
      ));
  }
```

Now when I rendered the form with renderpartial and changed my code in View file like this

```
 <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
  'data'=>$model,
  'attributes'=>array(
   'id',
   'customer_id',
    array(
      'label' => 'Firstname',
      'value' => $customers->firstname,
    ),
    array(
      'label' => 'Lastname',
      'value' => $customers->lastname,
    ),
    array(
      'label' => 'description',
      'value' => $customers->description,
    ),
  ),
)); ?>
```

It showed an error like this Trying to get property of non-object in line  'value' => $customers->firstname,
So can someone tell me where the wrong part?Any help and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: change your validation to something like this:
`
$valid = $model->validate();
$valid = $customers->validate() && $valid;
`

Comment: Ya I have changed it..It does not work.

Comment: so the actionView is in invoices controller? that means that the `loadModel($id)` is loading an invoice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think problem in follow code:

```
public function actionView($id)
  {
    $this->render('view',array(
      'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
      'customers'=>Invoices::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>$_GET['id']))->customer_id,
      ));
  }
```

Try this code:

```
public function actionView($id)
  {
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);
    $this->render('view',array(
      'model'=>$model,
      'customers'=>Customers::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>$model->customer_id)),
      ));
  }
```

Comment: in what line? Did you add $model = $this->loadModel($id);?

Answer (score 1):

What's the name of the relation to customers in the Invoices model? Let's say it's `customs`. You can try this:

```
  <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
  'data'=>$model,
  'attributes'=>array(
   'id',
   'customer_id',
    array(
      'label' => 'Firstname',
      'value' => $model->customs->firstname,
    ),
    array(
      'label' => 'Lastname',
      'value' => $model->customs->lastname,
    ),
    array(
      'label' => 'description',
      'value' => $model->customs->description,
    ),
  ),
)); ?>
```

But of course you have to replace `customs` with the actual name of the relation.

Comment: Nope..It is not working.The error is : Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 0):

This error says that you are trying to access a non-object. Most probably it is not populated from where you are rendering it.
to be sure do following

1. `echo CVarDumper($_GET['id'],100,true)`
2. `echo CVarDumper($customers,100,true)`

and let us know what is there.

So The `actionView()` should look like this

```
  public function actionView($id)
  {
    $this->render('view',array(
      'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
      `echo CVarDumper($_GET['id'],100,true)`
      yii::app()->end();
      'customers'=>Invoices::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>$_GET['id']))->customer_id,
      ));
  }
```

show what it displays.

step 2 undo above code to your orignal one and then add

```
echo CVarDumper($customers,100,true)
yii::app()->end();
```

before

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(.....
```

and then check what gets displayed

Comment: This should be used in which file?model,view or controller file?

Comment: 1 goes to your place where you are using `$_GET` and 2 goes in view file

Comment: I did not get you.Can you elaborate how to use it?

Comment: Actually I got confused in where to use it.I know It should use in controller and View file but in which line.It is showing inside that line.So I am confused

Comment: Hey Thanks for your quick reply.I tried your above code.It is showing only the id which is passing through the url.I had to change the code that you have mentioned above.I changed it like this   public function actionView($id)
    {
      $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
        CVarDumper::dump($_GET['id'],100,true),
        Yii::app()->end(),
        'customers'=>Invoices::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>$_GET['id']))->customer_id,
        ));
    }

Answer (score 0):

change

```
  'customers'=>Invoices::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>$_GET['id']))->customer_id,
```

to

```
  'customers'=>Invoices::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>$_GET['id'])),
```

you might still get the same error if findByAttributes returns null. So you have to check if $customers is null or not before you do $customers->firstname.

Comment: It is showing error as Firstname attribute is not from the Invoice model.The error is like this : Property "Invoices.firstname" is not defined.